# Cascading ComboBox will not display updated value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm using Winform ComboBoxes that I have filled with data from my MySQL datatables. They are cascading ComboBoxes, so whatever I select from the first ComboBox, which is country,  will determine the items in the second ComboBox called `City`
[Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mffv4.jpg)

My issue is that when I am updating my customer DataGridView, the item previously selected is not shown in the ComboBox for my Update form; the first item is shown by default. Strangely,  that is only an issue for the second ComboBox, `City`

[Update Form Showing the Incorrect City Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou9Nd.jpg)

The first one, `Country`, shows the previously selected item as it's intended to do.

[Update Form Showing the Correct Country Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J54hs.jpg)

When I close the Update form and then attempt to update the same exact customer, for the second time on the Main Screen, the `City` ComboBox shows the correct value.

[Update Form now shows the Correct value for both City and Country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb7Sk.jpg)

I wanted help in figuring out what I can do to get the previously selected value for the second combo box working properly. I also wanted to thank anyone in advance for any help or clarity that I can use to solve this issue.

Here is some of my code:

```
private void CBxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CBxCountry.SelectedValue.ToString() != null) 
    {
        countryId = Convert.ToInt32(CBxCountry.SelectedValue);
        refreshcity(countryId);
    }
}

private void refreshcity(int countryId)
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM city WHERE countryId = @countryId", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("countryId", countryId);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    CbxCity.DisplayMember = "city";
    CbxCity.ValueMember = "cityId";
    CbxCity.DataSource = dt;
    CbxCity.Enabled = true;
    City = this.CbxCity.GetItemText(this.CbxCity.SelectedItem);
}

public void UpdateCustomer() 
{
    LblAddUpdateCustomer.Text = "Update Customer";
    BtnUpdateSave.Text = "Update";
    TxtNameAdd.Text = CustomerName;
    TxtAddressAdd.Text = Address;
    CbxCity.Text = City;
    CBxCountry.Text = Country;
    TxtZipAdd.Text = PostalCode;
    TxtPhoneAdd.Text = Phone;
}
```

*This is my first time asking for help here so I hope I have given enough information.*

Comment: It would be relatively easy with a strongly typed dataset having 3 tables, (customer, city, country) and 3 datarelations (customer->city, customer->country city->country, arrows point to primary key end) and a form with a citybindingsource that is bound to the city_country datarelation exposed by the country bindingsource

Answer (score 0):

You dont set the SelectedItem of the ComboBox withing refreshCity.
You need to pass the actual gridvalue of your selected main datarow to refreshCity so you can "reselect" the item that was written in your main datagrid.

Within refreshCity you are just filling the comboBox and then you pass its default selected value to City. Here you have to set the comboBox.SelectedValue to whatever was in your griddata.

Edit: it seems you are saving the gridvalue in the City variable so instead of doing

City = this.CbxCity.GetItemText(this.CbxCity.SelectedItem);

you have to do it the other way around. set the selectedItem to city

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I did edit the code to this: CbxCity.SelectedItem = City; I think this puts me on the right track because when I step into the code the variable City now shows the city that I want, "Osaka" all the way through. But still, I get the first item "Kyoto" in my combo box when the Update form appears.